# Testing conversion from custom object to Spring Data Mongodb Criterias

Tags: spring, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-data-mongodb

I have more of a clean testing question: I have a `SearchObject` with attributes corresponding to fields in a mongodb. The `SearchObject` needs to be converted to a mongodb query for searching. As we are using spring data mongodb, first the `SearchObject` is converted to a List of `Criteria`s for searching. This is done in a seperate class, that has functions like these (displaying one very simple case):

```
private static String beginsWith(String match) { return "^" + Pattern.quote(match); }

public Criteria buildNameCriteria(SearchObject searchObject) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchObject.getName())) {
        return new Criteria();
    }
    return Criteria.where("name").regex(beginsWith(searchObject.getName()), "im");
}
```

Now what is the best way to write a unit test for such a method?

- Converting the Criteria to a Json and comparing it to a predefined value? (This can break easily with an update of spring data mongodb)
- Extracting the regex out of the Criteria and checking if it is the correct one?
- Mocking the Criteria methods and checking if they have been called?

Is there even a way to test such a method? Or should the Code be refactored to allow easier testing?
Keep in mind, that the code displayed is only an example and the actual Criterias are often more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to test that the criteria are doing what you expect, and are not interested in the inner workings of `Criteria`, or the actual regexes generated.

So I'd recommend for a SearchObject to set up test data: Documents that should and that should not be found. Make sure to include as many corner cases as you can; possibly ask a fellow engineer to come up with corner cases.
Put the test documents into a test DB and see if the SearchObject finds exactly those that it should.

Mock vs. real DB? Depends.
Writing the mock might take too much effort. It's also somewhat fragile against changes in the MongoDB driver.
Running in a real DB depends on whether you have a test environment, how big the differences to production are, and how much these differences would affect your code.